# Controlling how each catch in $httpBackend.when() is handled

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to build some jasmine unit tests around my angular project.  I've run into a situation I'm not sure how best to work around.

I use a response interceptor that's capable of retrying a request if it determines the error was a 401 error.  It will make a call to renew the authorization token, and then reissue the request transparently.

**(Orginal Call) -> 401 ? (recert and retry) : (return fail)**

My problem lies with:

```
$httpBackend.whenPOST('/mymockedendpoint').respond(401, null);
```

This is the behavior I want the FIRST time it is queried.  However, because it also controls all subsequent queries, my token renewal works, and then it reissues this request, but instead of returning a 200 like it would in production, it still returns the 401.

How can I extend the handling of that `whenPOST` so that I can control the behavior in a handler of some sort?  Is that even possible?

Right now executing my test produces an infinite loop because the both reissues the request (since it successfully renewed the token) and catches again because the would-be-200 requests returns a 401).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the "when" based functions of `$httpBackend` you can use the "expect" versions. This will let you assert that a particular request is made in a particular order. The [documentation for $httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) describes the differences pretty well:

> $httpBackend.expect - specifies a request expectation
>
> $httpBackend.when - specifies a backend definition
>
> **Request Expectations vs Backend Definitions**
>
> Request expectations provide a way
>   to make assertions about requests made by the application and to
>   define responses for those requests. The test will fail if the
>   expected requests are not made or they are made in the wrong order.
>
> Backend definitions allow you to define a fake backend for your
>   application which doesn't assert if a particular request was made or
>   not, it just returns a trained response if a request is made. The test
>   will pass whether or not the request gets made during testing.

Given that, try this in your test:

```
$httpBackend.expectPOST('/mymockedendpoint').respond(401, null);
$httpBackend.expectPOST('/mymockedendpoint').respond(200, { });
$httpBackend.flush();
```

Also, note the function `$httpBackend.resetExpectations()`, which could be useful in this type of scenario.

Comment: Works like a champ!  Thank you for highlighting the differences, that is exceptionally useful to know.